# function to check if an int is positive or negative using bitwise ops

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 32-bit

I am trying to write a C function which checks if a `int` is positive or not. This is what i have:

```
int isPositive(int x){
    return ~(x >> 31) & 0x1;
}
```

Depending on the number, this should return 1 is positive and 0 is not. It works for all the numbers but not for  `-2147483648`.

That number should fit in a 32bit vector with 2's complement. So why isn't it working?

To be precise, im in Visual Studio and it gives me a compile error of `C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned` however -2147483647 seems to work.

Comment: How did you enter the `-2147483648`? In code, that would be the unary `-` applied to the literal, not a literal *including* the `-`.  Since 2147483648 doesn't fit in an `int`, your literal gets the `unsigned` type.

Comment: return `num & 0x80000000`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, that's the same as OP's code and won't fix his problem, which is with code that's not here.

Comment: @CarlNorum I miss understood the question.

Comment: Pardon the obviousness, but `return (0 > x)` ? Shifting the sign-bit either in-to, or out-of, a negative integer is implementation-defined at-best. I.e., it can vary from one implementation to another, and thus you are better off to simply avoid it entirely.

Comment: @WhozCraig, the question title says "using bitwise ops".

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm aware of the question. My comment is about doing it in the first place.

Comment: Homework question, maybe. Sometimes people have weird requirements.

Comment: @CarlNorum Probably. I wonder how many of the students answers will fail when their project is compiled for 64-bit.

Comment: hi, yes this is a HW question. An i am specifically told to compile my app for a 32 bit cpu

Comment: @vidhu That explains it. Carl's answer is solid, and should be accepted. And your instructor should already know what I mentioned earlier (or we can only hope).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you enter the `-2147483648`? If you just typed it directly into your program, that would be the unary `-` applied to the literal, not a literal *including* the `-`.  Since 2147483648 doesn't fit in an `int`, your literal gets the `unsigned` type.

Either use `INT_MIN`, or use the trick most libraries use to define it:

```
 isPositive(-2147483647 - 1);
```

Comment: Happy to help.  Hopefully that unblocks you.

Answer (score 0):

Since C makes absolutely no guarantees about either the size of `int` or the numerical system used to store numbers (sign bit or otherwise), if you are trying to do this for any practical purpose, you probably shouldn't, use direct comparison with 0 for maximum portability. Even extending your type to a larger one to "protect" against overflowing is not going to help as C has very few guarantees about sign bit propagation and such.